# PHP & MongoDB: numeric field names return as "NumberLong(X)" string

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a data structure which contains an object with fields with numerical names, e.g.

```
{1 : {views:42, impressions:999}, 2 : {...} ...}
```

This is not an 'array', just an identifiers.
When I request those records via [PHP Mongo extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php) 1.4.4 (both mongo 2.4.7 and web server are running on Win7) I receive those keys as expected, i.e.

```
2
    impressions    9
    views          0
3
    impressions    9
    views          9
1
    impressions    50
    views          50
```

But when this code runs in staging environment (LAMP, where we have mongo driver 1.6.0-dev, mongodb itself is 2.4.2) I receive them this weird way:

```
NumberLong(2)
    impressions    9
    views          0
NumberLong(3)
    impressions    9
    views          9
NumberLong(1)
    impressions    50
    views          50
```

where 'NumberLong(X)' is plain string, coming right from my cursor.
It's not a big deal to fix this and replace numerical names with string ones, but I'm wondering what driver (or DB) behaves wrong and why.

Both servers have 'mongo.native_long' enabled.

Answer (score 2):

It behaves like this because of how it is setup: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.configuration.php

The setting you are looking for is: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.configuration.php#ini.mongo.native-long

Comment: Updated the question. Both servers have 'mongo.native_long' enabled.

Comment: @EugeneM Seems I didn't read quite close enough, though 1.6? I don't think there is a 1.6? https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases

Comment: Yes, actually it's 1.6.0-dev. Haven't noticed this before, this might be an issue.

Comment: @EugeneM yeah downgrade to stable, though it might still happen there, but I will carry on if it still does

Comment: The default value for this changed in 1.5.0 - and is forced on 32bits builds. See the updated changelog on the linked page.